# Transiting through Johannesburg to Maseru

Tags: visas, transit, ghanaian-citizens

I am a Ghanaian traveling to South Africa. I have a single entry visa to South Africa but I would like to visit Maseru first before entering South Africa.

I would like to have a direct flight to Maseru.

1. Can I transit at the airport without having my passport stamped as having enter South Africa and then later enter South Africa by road?
2. Do I need to pass through immigration before boarding the connecting flight to Maseru?
3. The ticket I am holding is Accra - Joberg - Accra. Will a separate booking for Joberg - Maseru be considered a valid proof that I am not entering South Africa this not needing to go through Immigration at the OR Tambo airport?

Comment: Do you have checked luggage? Which airline do you fly on the segment to Joburg and which on the segment to Lesotho?

Comment: [Related / possible duplicate](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38734/do-i-require-a-south-african-transit-visa/38776#38776), but I feel my answer was unclear then because I came up with competing requirements.

Comment: I will not carry any checked in luggage. South Africa airways to Joberg and Airlink to Maseru